# Sorting data in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 items that are to be sorted by Linq.

The 3 items are

1. 1.1 AAAAAA
2. 10.1 AAAAA
3. 1.11 AAAAA
4. 9.1 AAAAAA

The sorted list should be as

1. 1.1 AAAAA
2. 1.11 AAAA
3. 9.1 AAAAA
4. 10.1 AAAA

Here's my code:

```
var progTypes = (from mnuit in entities.MENU_ITEM
                 join mnu in entities.MENU on mnuit.MENU_ID equals mnu.MENU_ID
                 join prog in entities.PROG on mnuit.MENU_ITEM_ID equals prog.PROG_TYP_ID
                 where (mnuit.MENU_ITEM_CD == programmodel.selectedProgram && mnu.MENU_NM == "PROG_TYP_ID")
                 select new ProgramModel.lstProgTypes
                        {
                            PROG_ID = prog.PROG_ID,
                            PROG_NBR = prog.PROG_NBR,
                            PROG_NM = prog.PROG_NM,
                            PROG_MAX_AMT = prog.PROG_MAX_AMT,
                            PROG_START_DT = prog.PROG_START_DT,
                            PROG_END_DT = prog.PROG_END_DT
                        }).OrderBy(m => m.PROG_NM)
                          .ToList();

progModel.mProgTypes = progTypes;
```

Can you guys please help

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Please, be more specific how the sorting order is defined

Comment: Don't store the two (edit: apparently its three) different values in a single column.  Store them in their own separate columns; then the query becomes trivial.

Comment: And are the values supposed to change? in your unsorted list you have `1.1 AAAAAA` it looses an 'A' in your sorted list  `1.1 AAAAA`. All of them do.

Comment: To expand on what @Servy said, having two values stored in a single column is going to require you to come up with a custom sorting algorithm where you split the strings and do the comparisons between the first numeric portion and the last Alpha portion.

Comment: The prog_nm is defined such way to actually have both the number and names

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon And of course trying to get that translated into SQL so that the operation is done in the database is going to be, if not impossible, extremely hard.

Comment: @CoderUnknown **Don't do that**.  Store *one thing* in each column.  Don't mush several things into a single column.

Comment: @Servy - yes, it would not translate to SQL directly, and he would have to enumerate the linq query via ToList(), then apply the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the string represents something that is composite in nature. The ideal approach for dealing with situations like that is *not* storing the composite, but storing the individual parts instead. In your case that would mean storing a number, another number, and a string in three separate properties.

However, this is not always possible, perhaps because you are dealing with a legacy system where a poor design choice has been made, and now you are stuck with it. One way of dealing with a situation like that would be bringing the data into memory, and sorting it with a custom `IComparer<T>`.

Start by removing `OrderBy(...)` from your query. Since you call `ToList()` already, `progTypes` would have all its elements in memory. That is the way you want it. Now you can define a custom comparer, and do this:

```
progTypes = progTypes.OrderBy(m => m.PROG_NM, new NmComparer()).ToList();
```

The "magic" goes into `NmComparer`:

```
internal class NmComparer : IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string a, string b) {
        var tokA = a.Split('.', ' ');
        var tokB = b.Split('.', ' ');
        int res = int.Parse(tokA[0]).CompareTo(int.Parse(tokB[0]));
        if (res != 0) return res;
        res = int.Parse(tokA[1]).CompareTo(int.Parse(tokB[1]));
        if (res != 0) return res;
        return tokA[2].CompareTo(tokB[2]);
    }
}
```

The comparer assumes that the `PROG_NM` has three parts - two `int`s and a `string`. It splits both sides on a dot and a space, and then compares the results going from left to right, and giving priority to tokens on the left.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to store it all in one field.
Basically I just do three sorts. I have added more examples to make it clearer how it works.

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "1.1 AAAAAA",
    "10.1 AAAAA",
    "1.12 AAAAA",
    "1.11 AAAAA",
    "9.1 BAAAAA",
    "9.1 AAAAAA"
};

var result = from s in list
             let indexOfDot = s.IndexOf('.')
             let indexOfSpace = s.IndexOf(' ')
             orderby s.Substring(indexOfSpace)
             orderby Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(indexOfDot + 1, indexOfSpace - indexOfDot))
             orderby Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, indexOfDot))
             select s;
```

You can test it in LINQPad - http://share.linqpad.net/8p23tu.linq